# How to separate strings with comma character?

Tags: c#, string

I wanted to separate two strings by commas(ie.234,229) and i tried it by adding `String.Join()`. I have the below mentioned code where i am getting error on the last line.I know its a basic question to ask but i am new to C# programming language.

```
 string queryEventID = "";
    foreach (ListItem lstAssign in lstEvent.Items)
    {
       if (lstAssign.Selected == true)
         {                  
            queryEventID = queryEventID + lstAssign.Value + " "; //queryEventID(234 229)                   
            logfield = logfield + "," + lstEvent.SelectedItem.Text;
         }
    }                     
    string queryEventIDs=string.Join(",",queryEventID);//error(cannot convert from string to string[])
```

Comment: is queryEventID an array?  it looks like one big long string with spaces in .. how do you expect it to work that out

Comment: Please show how data in `queryEventID` looks like after the loop runs. And that is the expected output

Comment: the second parameter in `string.Join()` must be an array.

Comment: Just after the if statement, i think you want `+=` rather than `=`. This will append to the string instead of overwriting it each time. You could add the comma at that point as well

Comment: i am selecting 2 events from the listbox Say A whose id is 234 and B whose id is 229.After looping,queryEventID takes selected event's ids which is 234 229.....i want it as 234,229

Comment: Use `Replace` function if you want to use string. Replace spaces with comma. Or use Array and pass it to `string.Join` (as stated in error.)

Comment: @MrJF....for this statement: queryEventID = queryEventID + lstAssign.Value + " "; ?

Comment: i tried using this:    queryEventID = queryEventID + lstAssign.Value + ",";

Comment: It gives me as "234,229,".....one extra comma at the end of the second string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a `Collection` to apply [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx).

From the documentation:

> `Join(String, String[])`:      Concatenates all the elements of a string array, using the specified separator between each element.

Here's an example of how to use it in your situation.

```
List<string> queryEventIDList;
foreach (ListItem lstAssign in lstEvent.Items)
{
    if (lstAssign.Selected == true)
    {
        queryEventIDList.Add(lstAssign.Value);                 
        logfield = logfield + "," + lstEvent.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
}
string queryEventIDs = string.Join(",", queryEventIDList);
```

Comment: i am getting here as cannot convert from System.collections.generic.list<string> to string[] for queryEventIDList

Comment: (I just edited the answer to include this...) Use the `ToArray()` method on `queryEventIDList` like this: `string queryEventIDs = string.Join(",", queryEventIDList.ToArray());`

Comment: No, it should work with List and other collections which is implemented from "IEnumarable<string>". There would be different case in here.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the split function to convert your string to collection.

```
        string queryEventID = "";
        foreach (ListItem lstAssign in lstEvent.Items)
        {
            if (lstAssign.Selected == true)
            {
                queryEventID = queryEventID + lstAssign.Value + " "; //queryEventID(234 229)                   
                logfield = logfield + "," + lstEvent.SelectedItem.Text;
            }
        }

        string queryEventIDs = string.Join(",", queryEventID.Split(' '));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try *Linq* in order to *query* the collection:

```
using System.Linq;

... 

string queryEventID = string.Join(",", lstEvent  // Join query data:  
  .Items                                         //   Having lstEvent.Items
  .OfType<ListItem>()                            //   Obtain IEnumerable<ListItem>
  .Where(item => item.Selected)                  //   Selected only
  .Select(item => item.Value));                  //   Value (not item)
```

If you want a *collection* of ids, array `string[]`:

```
string[] queryEvents = lstEvent  
  .Items                             
  .OfType<ListItem>()                
  .Where(item => item.Selected)      
  .Select(item => item.Value)
  .ToArray();

string queryEventID = string.Join(",", queryEvents);
```

Comment: cannot convert from System.collections.generic.list<string> to string[] for queryEvents(last line)

Comment: Thank u so much friend...:)..It Worked greatly...:)